# How to save html content in mongodb via SpringBoot form

Tags: html, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a SpringBoot based MVC application which uses mongoDB to store the data. I am using thymeleaf as the template engine. In one of the scenarios, the user needs to fill a form which is then displayed on some view.

The problem I am facing is that the user can use html tags to format the data while writing in the textArea of the form (code snippets, tabular format etc). But when I am displaying that text, the html is not being parsed and is displayed as is.

**For Ex:** <b>String</b> should be displayed as **String** but is being displayed as <b>String</b> only. When I check the source code of the page, the html tags are displayed as encoded i.e. < is showing as &lt ; etc and hence the parsing is not happening.

Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output unescaped text with `th:utext`. From the [official turorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text)

> If we want Thymeleaf to respect our XHTML tags and not escape them, we will have to use a different attribute: `th:utext` (for “unescaped text”):

```
<p th:utext="#{home.welcome}">Welcome to our grocery store!</p>
```

The tutorial assumes that `home.welcome` is a string with html-tags:
`home.welcome=Welcome to our <b>fantastic</b> grocery store!`.

It goes without saying that this needs very careful validation so that only safe (whatever *safe* is for the particular use case) `HTML` is stored into the database (and no possibly malicious code like `<script/>` tags).